# Making column sum of adjacency matrix even.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matrix-equations

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $V$ vertices and let say I have an adjacency matrix of order $N$, how can I make sum of each column even?

Like I have a graph with $4$ vertices and $4$ edges as

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
                0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
                0  & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix}$

And I want to convert it like this,

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
                1  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
                0  & 0 &  0 &  0\\
                1 & 0 & 1 & 0   \end{bmatrix}$

For reference, if $i^{th}$ element of the $j^{th}$ row is $1$ then the edge is directed from $j$ to $i$.

You can reverse any edge between two vertices such that the graph remains connected. And the adjacency matrix's indexing starts from 1 rather than from 0.

Comment: Depends on what operations you allow yourself to use.

Comment: I've added the operation which you can use in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this depends on what operations you allow, because you are clearly allowing your underlying graph to change --- the graph after your transformation  isn't isomorphic to the first graph.

For your first matrix, you have the following graph:

[image: First graph]

For your second matrix, you have the following:

[image: Second graph]

Taken as directed graphs, these are not isomorphic (however, if you relax them to merely undirected, they are).  As such, it's difficult to determine what operations you're allowing as legal transformations.

Comment: I've added the allowed operation in the last sentence of the question. Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @SahilSilare with those rules, you still might not be able to do so.  Consider the graph formed by two nodes with one edge like so: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  No matter what, you can't get an even number of $1$'s in a single column/row.

Comment: I'm not saying even number of ones, I'm saying to make the the sum of each column even, it can be either $0$ or $2$ or any even number.

Comment: @SahilSilare "even number of 1s" is equivalent to "even sum of values" since every value is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Can't you just reverse the direction between 2 odd column indexes?

Comment: Consider $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ (sorry I messed up my example in the above comment).

Comment: Even if you reverse the direction, you'll just get $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.